# Storing values for future math with javascript

Tags: jquery, algorithm

Evening gents, I got a tough one, and im not sure if this is the correct way to go about this or not but here goes... basically im creating a dynamic calendar, and currently im working on the month back function (you click the arrow, it goes back) i have a jquery function that starts other functions onclick, so far everything works, the calendar gets redrawn a month back, the name of the month goes back one, however i am having a problem setting the year back 1, To elaborate further... the month name is redrawn by an ajax query(php) and it works perfectly, and from what i can tell my javascript should be working great as well. basically whenever it goes back a year, im storing a number in `<div id = "placeholder>` to use as reference point. That sounds complicated hopefully the code will make more sense, and if anyone can find a beter way to do this please let me know:

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#changeMonthBack").click(function() {

//ajax query for month title
function(data) {
    //responce is here
    //set year (n)
        var placeholder = parseInt($("#placeholder").attr('class'),10);

        if(str == 1 && placeholder == ""){
            var d = new Date();
            var n = d.getFullYear();
            n = n - 1;
            $("#placeholder").addClass("1");
        }

        else if(str == 1 && placeholder != ""){
            var d = new Date();
            var n = d.getFullYear();
            n = n - placeholder;
            var temp = placeholder + 1;
            $("#placeholder").removeClass(""+placeholder+"");
            $("#placeholder").addClass(""+temp+"");
        }

        else{
            var d = new Date();
            var n = d.getFullYear();
        }



        $("#monthYear").html(data +" "+ n);
```

HTML:

```
    <li title = "Previous Month"  id = "changeMonthBack"></li>
    <div id = "placeholder"></div><!-- holder for year js -->
    <div id = "monthYear">
```

currently after getting to 2013 it gives my a NaN error. any and all help would be lovely. If any more information could help just let me know

Comment: If you `parseInt` an empty string, you will get `NaN` back. So your tests of `placeholder` against an empty string make no sense. Your `placeholder` variable is already `NaN`. Also, why are you using the class to store data? Use the `data-` attributes.

Comment: @MattBurland suppose i should have added that im new to jquery, and even javascript.

Comment: Yeah, it's really not clear what you are trying to do. Is there a reason why you want to store data in a DOM element in the first place instead of a JavaScript variable? A fiddle would *really* help.

Comment: the button re runs the query every time its clicked, would a js variable not be lost every time? If not then im going to feel really dumb

Comment: Depends. If the whole thing is wrapped in a closure, and the variable is defined outside of your click function, then no. Or if you use a global variable (which isn't recommended). Can you show some more code (with your click handler) to put this in context?

Comment: @MattBurland added the handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var placeholder = 0;

    $("#changeMonthBack").click(function() {
        //....
        function(data) {
            //responce is here
            //set year (n)
            if(str == 1 && placeholder === 0) {
                var d = new Date();
                var n = d.getFullYear();
                n = n - 1;
               placeholder = 1;
            }

            else if(str == 1 && placeholder > 0) {
                var d = new Date();
                var n = d.getFullYear();
                n = n - placeholder;
                placeholder++;
            }
        }
        //....
    });

});
```

You can now use the variable `placeholder` within your `click` handler (and within deeper nested functions) because your nested function has access to variables defined in the outer closure.

Now you don't need to mess about with storing data in the DOM.